# Property population via `wither` methods

Tags: couchbase, immutability, lombok, spring-data-couchbase

[Property Population](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/couchbase/docs/3.1.4.RELEASE/reference/html/#mapping.property-population) isn't working as expected for me when using immutable objects.

I'm attempting to follow the [Property Population](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/couchbase/docs/3.1.4.RELEASE/reference/html/#mapping.property-population) section of the [spring-data-couchbase-3.1.4.RELEASE reference docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/couchbase/docs/3.1.4.RELEASE/reference/html/) which suggests that it I can pass in a immutable entity with an appropriate `@wither` method for setting the id. However, when I attempted it the returned entity still has a `null` value for the ID.

[com/example/demospringdatacouchbaseapp/model/Car.java](https://github.com/LewisWatson/demo-spring-data-couchbase-app/blob/0.0.1/src/main/java/com/example/demospringdatacouchbaseapp/model/Car.java)

```java
import static org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.mapping.id.GenerationStrategy.USE_ATTRIBUTES;
import org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.mapping.Document;
import org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.mapping.id.GeneratedValue;
import org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.mapping.id.IdAttribute;
import com.couchbase.client.java.repository.annotation.Field;
import com.couchbase.client.java.repository.annotation.Id;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Value;
import lombok.experimental.Wither;

@Value
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder(toBuilder=true)
@Document
public class Car {

  public static final String ID_DELIMITER = ".";

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = USE_ATTRIBUTES, delimiter = ID_DELIMITER)
  @Wither
  String id;

  @Field
  @IdAttribute(order=0)
  String manufacturer;

  @Field
  @IdAttribute(order=1)
  String model;

  @Field
  @IdAttribute(order=2)
  String spec;

  @Field
  String colour;

}
```

[com/example/demospringdatacouchbaseapp/repository/CarRepository.java](https://github.com/LewisWatson/demo-spring-data-couchbase-app/blob/0.0.1/src/main/java/com/example/demospringdatacouchbaseapp/repository/CarRepository.java)

```java
import java.util.Collection;
import org.springframework.data.couchbase.repository.CouchbaseRepository;
import com.example.demospringdatacouchbaseapp.model.Car;

public interface CarRepository extends CouchbaseRepository<Car, String> {

  Collection<Car> findByColour(String colour);

}
```

[Create simple car test](https://github.com/LewisWatson/demo-spring-data-couchbase-app/blob/0.0.1/src/test/java/com/example/demospringdatacouchbaseapp/repository/CarRepositoryIT.java#L28)

```java
  @Test
  public void createSingCarTest() {

    /*
     * Given
     */

    Car givenCar = createMadWeeClio();

    /*
     * When
     */

    Car persistedCar = repository.save(givenCar);

    /*
     * Then
     */

    assertThat(persistedCar).isEqualTo(givenCar.withId(getExpectedId(givenCar)));

  }

  ...

  private String getExpectedId(Car givenCar) {
    return givenCar.getManufacturer() + Car.ID_DELIMITER + givenCar.getModel() + Car.ID_DELIMITER
        + givenCar.getSpec();
  }

  private Car withExpectedId(Car car) {
    return car.withId(getExpectedId(car));
  }

  private Car createMadWeeClio() {
    return Car.builder().manufacturer("RenaultSport").model("Clio").spec("200 Cup").colour("white")
        .build();
  }

  private Car createMadMeg() {
    return Car.builder().manufacturer("RenaultSport").model("Megane").spec("R.S Trophy")
        .colour("Yellow").build();
  }
```

I expected the `CouchbaseRepository::save` operation to return a new instance of my immutable entity object with the auto-generated ID property filled in. However, its coming back as `null` in my tests.

Passing in a mutable entity results in the id field being set as expected. I can also see the ID field being populated in couchbase.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is that the `save` operation is not creating a new instance of your `Car` object - rather it will try and set the id onto the object (but can't since its immutable).

The `@Value` Lombok annotation results in a method which looks like

```
Car withId(String id) {
    return new Car(id, this.model, this.spec, this.colour);
}
```

but this method is not called when you `save` your object.

When you retrieve the object from the database the `withId` method is called. So if you return all the objects from the database (or search for it using some other criteria such as model) you'll see that they do infact have id properties with values.  The documentation covers this here:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/couchbase/docs/3.1.4.RELEASE/reference/html/#mapping.property-population

Comment: Thanks for the response @robjwilkins. It was that section of the documentation that led me to believe that spring-data-couchbase will use the wither method to create a new instance of the immutable object before returning from the save method. 


Specifically the line that states:


> If the property is immutable but exposes a wither method (see below), we use the wither to create a new entity instance with the new property value.

Comment: The [General Recommendations section also recommends using immutable objects and lombok](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/couchbase/docs/3.1.4.RELEASE/reference/html/#_general_recommendations), so surely there is some way to make it all work.